# SharePoint Online Create Site Collection using REST api?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, site-collection

Is it possible to create a site collection using the SharePoint Online REST api?

I found some old notes about using admin.asmx in 2007/2010/2013 but I can't find anything related to SharePoint online or if it still exists.

An example URL would be amazing if it's possible.

Comment: I've used the PnP library and Flows with Azure functions, but haven't explored the ReST route yet. I'm assuming it would be a lot easier than those 2 methods.

Comment: What type of site collection would you like to create ? Do you want to create modern communication and team sites ?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Online Rest API provide endpoint to create a sub site but not site collection, see my reply in the similiar thread:

[Create the site collection using ECMAScript, JSOM Or Rest API](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/66cac1b7-5b7a-4a48-86c1-76e9fb125852/create-the-site-collection-using-ecmascript-jsom-or-rest-api?forum=appsforsharepoint)

And web service http://CentralAdmin/_vti_adm/Admin.asmx is not suitable for SharePoint Online, as there is no CA for SPO, this is for On-Premise Environment.

You could use PnP PowerShell New-PnPSite Command to create a site collection instead:

[New-PnPSite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/new-pnpsite?view=sharepoint-ps)

Answer (score -3):

Its possible to create Site collection using the Rest API.

Here is the code for Site Collection if you want to create a Communication Site collection in Tenant.

```
var body={
    "request":{
        "__metadata":{"type":"SP.Publishing.CommunicationSiteCreationRequest"},
        "AllowFileSharingForGuestUsers":false,
        "Classification":"IT",
        "Description":"Here is my communication site",
        // "SiteDesignId" - use either of the below 3 options
        //"SiteDesignId":"f6cc5403-0d63-442e-96c0-285923709ffc",
        //"SiteDesignId":null,
        "SiteDesignId":"6142d2a0-63a5-4ba0-aede-d9fefca2c767",
        "Title":"My Test Communication Site",
        "Url":"https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/testcommunicationsite",            
        "lcid":1033
    }
};


jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/_api/sitepages/communicationsite/create",
    contentType: "application/json",
    processData: false,
    data: JSON.stringify(body),
    headers:{
        "accept":"application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type":"application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value
    },        
    success: function () {
        console.log("creation request submitted");
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log("failure");
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Hope this code helps.

ref: https://gautamdsheth.wordpress.com/2017/10/04/spo-create-communication-sites-using-rest-api/

Here is the code i have got from MS for Subsite.

```
function createSite() {

        var newSiteTitle = "Site Title Test";

        var newSiteDesc = "Site Title Desc";

        var newSiteUrl = newSiteTitle.replace(/\s/g, "");

        var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;

        var fullUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/webinfos/add";

        $.ajax({

            url: fullUrl,

            type: "POST",

            data: JSON.stringify({

                'parameters': {

                    '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.WebInfoCreationInformation' },

                    'Url': newSiteUrl,

                    'Title': newSiteTitle,

                    'Description': newSiteDesc,

                    'Language': 1033,

                    'WebTemplate': 'sts#0',

                    'UseUniquePermissions': false

                }

            }),

            headers: {

                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",

                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",

                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()

            },

            success: onQuerySucceeded,

            error: onQueryFailed

        });

    }

    function onQuerySucceeded() {

       alert("Site Created Successfully!");

    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

        alert('Error!');

    }
```

ref link :https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37458.sharepoint-online-office-365-create-site-using-rest-api.aspx

Comment: This will create a subsite - not a site collection